# React Router v6 rendering blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm kinda new to react and currently learning. I kinda stucked at this stage - As i started writing a ChatInput component for an another  component which was already imported to App.js and to Chat.js as well. But as i saved and refreshed the code. The react router is rendering a blank page. While there's no error in the code.This problem didnt showed up and the page was rendering fine inspite of the chat component was there but without ChatInput.js.

But now even if i include the  component into App.js. the react router renders a blank page and if i removes  component from app.js. The code renders the elements.

Please help as i'm new and cant able to figure out What's the issue.
I'm currently on React-router V6

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/Header'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'
import Chat from './components/Chat'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <AppBody>
          <Sidebar />
          <Chat />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element=""></Route>
          </Routes>
        </AppBody>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App

const AppBody = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
`
```

**Chat.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import StarBorderOutLinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/StarBorderOutlined'
import InfoOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/InfoOutlined'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { selectRoomId } from '../features/appSlice'
import ChatInput from './ChatInput'
import styled from 'styled-components'

function Chat() {
  const roomId = useSelector(selectRoomId)
  return (
    <ChatContainer>
      <>
        <Header>
          <HeaderLeft>
            <h4>
              <strong>#Room-name</strong>
            </h4>
            <StarBorderOutLinedIcon />
          </HeaderLeft>
          <HeaderRight>
            <p>
              <InfoOutlinedIcon /> Details
            </p>
          </HeaderRight>
        </Header>

        <ChatMessages></ChatMessages>
        <ChatInput channelId={roomId} />
      </>
    </ChatContainer>
  )
}

export default Chat

const ChatContainer = styled.div`
  flex: 0.7;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-top: 60px;
`

const Header = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
`

const HeaderLeft = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  > h4 {
    display: flex;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  > h4 > .MuiSvgIcon-root {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
`

const HeaderRight = styled.div`
  > p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  > p > .MuiSvgIcon-root {
    margin-right: 5px !important;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
`
const ChatMessages = styled.div``
```

**ChatInput.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'

function ChatInput(channelName, channelId) {
  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  return (
    <ChatInputContainer>
      <form>
        <input placeholder={'Message #ROOM'} />
        <Button hidden type="submit" onClick={sendMessage}>
          Send
        </Button>
      </form>
    </ChatInputContainer>
  )
}

export default ChatInput

const ChatInputContainer = styled.div`
  border-radius: 20px;

  > form {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  > form > input {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
    outline: none;
  }
  > form > button {
    display: none !important;
  }
`
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import { store } from './app/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Sorry, do you have an issue with your chat components, or some issue with `react-router-dom` and rendering a page? None of the chat components are rendering by any routing components, and the one `Route` you have is rendering nothing. Can you clarify more precisely the issue?

Comment: Sorry for not simplifying my question. Actually I have problem with react router as my page is rendering blank as i included the Chat component (Which was previously wasnt happening even with Chat component included, but now it returns a blank page ).

Comment: @DrewReese I'm trying to return my App.js page. Sorry as i'm new. Though there's nothing been rendered by react-router. I'm still not able to figuring out why app.js returning a Blank page, when i add Chat component. Please help me out with these problem.

Comment: I see. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue you see that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese Sure

Comment: @DrewReese https://codesandbox.io/live/1e4a456ee74

Comment: Code seems to run fine in that CSB, but it also seems to be missing the chat components?

Comment: @DrewReese Could you again check it. it seems i somehow shared the old repository. Here's the updated one : https://codesandbox.io/live/1170a45e65d

Comment: When you run the CSB do you have any errors? I found that the `appSlice` reducer wasn't added to the store correctly, but once fixed I see your app appear to render just fine.

Comment: @DrewReese could share the fix you did in the store.

Comment: `reducer: { counter: appReducer }` -> `reducer: { app: appReducer }` to match the selector function. https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-cohen-yrfeg?file=/src/app/store.js

Comment: Great! We'll just call this a typo and I'll vote to close as such. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Index.js

```
        import React from 'react'
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
        import './index.css'
        import App from './App'
        import { store } from './app/store'
        import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
        import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
        import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
        
        ReactDOM.render(
          <React.StrictMode>
            <Provider store={store}>
              <BrowserRouter>
                <App />
              </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
          </React.StrictMode>,
          document.getElementById('root'),
        )
        
        // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
        // unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
        
        serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/Header'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'
import Chat from './components/Chat'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={
          <>
            <Header />
            <AppBody>
              <Sidebar />
              <Chat />
            </AppBody>
          </>
        } />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But still renders a blank page inspite of the changes you suggested.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find a fix?

Comment: What does the console in the browser say? Are there any errors being flagged?

Comment: I faced the same issue and checking the reducer it was the problem